# What is the name of the maker of this bokken?

Tags: bokken

I'd like to know the name of the maker of this bokken, which I purchased in France some years ago:

[image: Bokken]

To make it easier to read the characters, I have traced them (correctly this time):

[image: Characters]

Comment: The first kanji is "separate", I think.

Comment: The second might be "grade 4"

Comment: It's also not far from the kanji for "bokuto", 木刀

Comment: I dropped a link over in the Japanese SE chat room. The indication was that TonyD's answer is correct, essentially it means "New".

Answer (score 4):

Your tracing isn't quite right: the bokken has a short down stroke at the top of the left character.  The correct kanji is shown below, is pronounced "shin" or "arata", and means "new" in English.

## 新

Unfortunately, it's such a ubiquitous kanji that I haven't been able to narrow search matches down to anything useful.

Comment: Thank you I have updated the image.

Comment: I believe you're right. My answer is probably wrong. I found this kanji in the following link... Google translate says the first character is "shin", second character is "dome". So the character that's on your bokken is likely "shin". https://www.sinonome-japan.com/en/bokken/97-aikido-quality-wooden-sword.html

Comment: @DanieleProcida: You're welcome.  By the way, the updated image isn't quite right... it should have that small downward stroke at the top left.

Comment: @SteveWeigand: I must admit I "cheated" a bit - my partner's Japanese and I went straight for the "hey, what's this kanji?" - actually got confused for a bit when told the first version of the trace wasn't the same as the photo - so hard to tell.

Comment: The real question is why is it "shin"? What's the significance of it? I know it means "new", but does that mean it's natural wood or something? Or is it "shin" as in "spirit" or "live"?

Comment: @SteveWeigand: I suspect it's being used as a brand name, and that likely because it was part of the name of the person who created the company or crafted the bokken.  It's sometimes used as a first name for boys or girls 
 - https://japanese-names.info/first_name/shin/ - but can also be used as a surname - where it's pronounced "arata" (on vs kun readings) - search for "arata" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_name.  But as you say it could have been chosen to describe the company or wood or even the spirit with which it was to be wielded as fresh and new....

Comment: With the circle around it, it suggests a name. So you're probably right that it might be part of a family or company name.

Answer (score 4):

I believe I have an answer for you about the manufacturer.
There is a circle around the character, which is common in Japanese for use in brand names, logos, indicating special meanings, and so on. In this usage circle is "maru" so I searched for 丸新 (Marushin) and found [this company](http://zenbukyo.jp/company.html) (#14 of the last section, same information as below).

> 新留木刀製作所    Niidome Bokutou Seisakujo
>   新留　義昭            Niidome Yoshiaki
>   〒885-0017         〒 indicates zipcode
>   宮崎県都城市年見町10街区8号    Miyazaki-ken Miyakonojo-shi Toshimi-cho 10-gaiku 8-go
>   tel:0986-23-1098
>   fax:0986-23-1098
>   木刀製造業     Manufacturer of bokutou

Their [website](https://niidomebokutou.info/). The representative's name is 新留　義昭 (Niidome Yoshiaki. 新 is read nii [like knee] in some names). It looks like the symbol comes from the first character of their last name, but there was no image of such a mark on their website. So while it's possible this is where it came from, I can't guarantee it.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is an excellent addition, thank you for the digging and the find!